# Dockerized zabbix agent monitoring docker container

Tags: docker, zabbix

I ve managed to run a dockerized zabbix (agent,server and db) and i need to monitor docker containers running on the host machine where the zabbix agent is also dockerized.

All the tutorials i ve found dont use dockerized zabbix agent but an agent installed on the host machine.

Is it possible to monitor docker container from inside a container (containerized zabbix agent) ? If yes, how can we configure so it works?

I see it's possible here :
https://github.com/digiapulssi/docker-zabbix-agent

But the repo is no longer maintained...

Thank you

Comment: For that you need to monitor from base machine only

Comment: `Is it possible..` `I see it's possible` Yes it is possible. You even found the whole repo... `is no longer maintained...` So update it if you need to and use. I would mount docker to the same path in the container as on the host, not in `/host/....`.

Comment: you might want to use the official repo https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker/

Comment: I have used the official repo but my dockerized agent cant see other docker containers. it works with normal agent